# How to build divs in a controller and place on a page where needed

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am querying a database for locations. I get the response from a stored procedure. When it returns the results, I want to build cards/articles/forms/etc. from the results and place inside a container on the page. I know how to echo a piece of div but it sits on top of the page. How do I build these pieces and then place them within a certain div in the page?

This is the part of the controller that builds the page.

```
 $results = DB::select('CALL Finder(?, ?, ?, ?)', array($latDown, 
      $latUp, $longDown, $longUp));

 foreach($results as $result){
     //Here is where I want to build the divs
 }
```

This is the blade.php file with the html for the results section

```
@extends('layouts.mainlayout')
@section('content')

<div class="container" style="height 55rem;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="locations_results" style="overflow-y: auto; width: 40%; height: 55rem;">
        <!--Here is where I want the results to go-->
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="">
        @include('layouts.map')
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what to try and my google searches haven't worked out very well. Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need build div in controllers? since we can do it in blade. i can reveal to you the solution for loop in blade but i need to know your reason first.

Comment: @WilliamGunawan can you please elaborate on " since we can do it in blade"? This is my first blade website

Comment: Don't build divs in controller..... divs should only be in views or in view components....you send only data to divs/views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not build your html within the controller. Since this is your first time using blade, I'll provide a simple example below.

First, pass the data from your controller to the view.

```php
$results = ...(your query)...

return view('your-view', compact('results'));
```

Then build your results within the view using blade directives (e.g., `@foreach`).

```php
@extends('layouts.mainlayout')
@section('content')

<div class="container" style="height 55rem;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="locations_results" style="overflow-y: auto; width: 40%; height: 55rem;">

        <!--Here is where I want the results to go-->

        @foreach ($results as $result)

            <!-- Use double curly braces for showing variable data -->
            {{ $result->id }}

        @endforeach

    </div>
    <div class="col" style="">
        @include('layouts.map')
    </div>
</div>
```